# string code showing error?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main()  
{  
  char s[] = "churchgate: no church no gate";  
  char t[25];  
  char *ss, *tt;  
  ss = s;  
  while (*ss != '\0')  
    *tt++ = *ss++;  
  printf("%s\n", t);  
  return 0;  
}
```

what is the problem with this code?
when I try to run it. Its showing up some garbage values.

Comment: Writing through an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: Add `static_assert(sizeof(s) <= 25, "Bad bad bad.");`

Comment: @Lundin, I'd suggest `char t[sizeof(s)];` instead. Especially, taking into account it's `c`-tagged.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker That's fine too, of course. And static_assert is part of the C language, since C11.

Answer (score 3):

You never point `tt` to anything. You need to point it to `t`:

```
tt=t;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You forgot to inialize `tt` to `t`
2. Your array is too small.
3. You forgot to null terminate your array.

Comment: Who cares about 2, given 1? :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker yes, I'm trying to be exhaustive;)

Answer (score 1):

Tho it can be fun to experiment with arbitrary locations in memory, if you want a defined behaviour the target of access has to be defined.

tt has to be pointed towards some defined area in memory space before you do operations on it.

```
*tt++ = *ss++;
```

`s` is 30 bytes. `t`, if that is the one you want to use for `tt` is 25.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker; you are very correct, I was a bit to dyslectic in counting chars there. Thanks :)

Comment: That's because instead of counting I've pasted it into console `echo -n ....|wc -c` (and added one for terminator) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1) "tt" was never initialized, and

2) "s[]" might be *READ ONLY* (depending on compiler/platform)!!!!!

Suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STRING 80

int 
main()  
{  
  char s[MAX_STRING] = "churchgate: no church no gate";
  char t[MAX_STRING];  
  char *ss = s, *tt = t;
  while (*ss)  
    *tt++ = *ss++;
  *tt = '\0'; 
  printf("%s\n", t);  
  return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities, e. g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main()  
{  
  char s[] = "churchgate: no church no gate";  
  char t[25];  
  char *ss, *tt;  
  for (ss=s, tt=t; *ss != '\0' && tt-t < sizeof(t)-1; ss++, tt++)
    *tt = *ss;
  }
  *tt = '\0';

  // or just use strncpy.
  // strncpy doesn't copy the \0 if the size is reached,
  // so account for that.
  strncpy(t, s, sizeof(t)-1);
  t[sizeof(t)-1] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", t);
  return 0;  
}
```

You know your major problems from the other answers:

1. `tt` uninitialized
2. no bounds checking for `t`
3. no 0-termination after copying